# Uncountable family of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution, independence

Let $\{ \xi _a \}_{a \in [0;1]}$ be a family of independent uniformly distributed on $[0;1]$ random variables on some probability space 
$(\Omega, \mathscr{F},P)$, indexed by a continuous parameter. Let $u$ be an independent of $\{ \xi _a \}_{a \in [0;1]}$ uniformly distributed on $[0;1]$ random variable. For $\omega \in \Omega$, define the map

$$
\alpha : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \ \ \\   \ \alpha (\omega) = \xi_{u(\omega)} (\omega).
$$

Is $\alpha$ a random variable?

I think the answer is negative, since the family $\{ \xi _a \}_{a \in [0;1]}$ is uncountable. How could I prove this?

Comment: why does uncountability mean it is not a r.v.?

Comment: it appears to me this is just a composition of two measurable function (aka random variables), so it is measurable (aka a random variable)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you consider $\{ \xi _a \}_{a \in [0;1]}$ as a function of $a$, it does not have to be measurable.

Comment: The first function maps w onto u(w), the second maps constant $a$ onto $\xi(a)$, how is this not composition of two functions. For measure theory to work, any sort of intuive things, such as this example, should all be measurable, else it is a crap theory.

Comment: As it stands, you have not specified your sample space. I see your concern and it is not as easy as i thought. I actually asked a similar question before about a bm.

Comment: @Lost1 Could you give a link?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315144/two-questions-about-brownian-motion the first question and see the karatzas and shreve reference. this question is different though...

Comment: A counter-example was given by Nate Eldredge at [Math Overflow][1].


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173037/uncountable-family-of-random-variables

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question was answered off-site